# PHPUnit won't test my files

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to test my files in PHP but I keep getting this error message:

> "/Users/Nakazai/XAMPP/bin/php" "/Applications/NetBeans/phpunit-old.phar" "--colors" "--log-junit" "/var/folders/ll/twrzpc8j77d3npwp2m_137mm0000gn/T/nb-phpunit-log.xml" "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bank1/Tests"
>
> PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> unrecognized option --run
>
> Done.

Appreciate your help, folks!

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit do not has command `--run` which you used in last argument. Check your NetBeans configuration, maybe your IDE try to run PHPUnit older than 4 (actually is version 5) and you have installed newer version.